# How do I fully rid of the 1px wide sidebar border?

Tags: sidebar

https://paecdev.com/federal-way-performing-arts-foundation/

Arrow pointing to border in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpCTQ.jpg

On the above page, I tried many CSS tricks, but I can't fully get rid of this 1px border between sidebar and main content. It is very faint, but if you look closely it's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your in themes style.css at a certain breakpoint `min-width: 769px` it's adding a border right. You could get rid of it by adding the following to your child themes CSS or The Customizers CSS Panel:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .ast-right-sidebar #primary {
        border-right: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: great it worked. looks like it's #primary and #secondary, too.